# Can't find elementary matrix as I do not know the order of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]
Hi,

Usually I would start using an identity matrix based on matrix $A(m×n)$ an order $m$, but since they only have $B$ be I cannot determine order $n$ thus I am not sure the size of the identity matrix I should start with to find the elementary matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary matrices can be used to perform row (or column) operations via matrix multiplication.

For example: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} A$ would add the first and second row of $A$ and write it into the second row of the product.
Now note that every elementary matrix is invertible (why?).

But I'm not sure why you write that $A$ is and $m \times n$ matrix. $B$ is a square matrix and C is invertible(so it is a square matrix as well). So $B=CA$ implies that A also must be a square matrix.